# How to error in manage

Tags: asp.net

i have designed web application in asp.net...i have publish a website..
i have create virtual directory and copy the publish file....
and browse the website...

The error r occure

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
> request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it
> originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

[image]

Comment: You're trying to use a null variable.  We won't be able to tell you more than that without source code and the stack trace.

Comment: does it run ok in the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

To see the actual details about the error, You have to set `customErrors mode="Off"` in the web.config

```
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="error.aspx"> 
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="ileNotFound.htm"/> 
</customErrors>
```

If you are able to get the details of error, then you will know where the problem is and then you will be able to fix it.

Comment: did you add this on hosting server website ? Seconly can you take the screen shot of error page and paste it in your question.

Comment: How to add screen shot in a question

Comment: take a screen shot and save it as image, then edit your question and add that image in your question